# How would I keep tracking of paginated value in my controller and display a certain amount of records per page?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, pagination

I'm getting paginated values from a query that lives inside a repository.  However, in my controller (snippet below) - I want to keep track of the current paginated page the user's on and would like to display records if, say, the user's on page 1, then get items 1-30.

(30 entries will be the max allowed on one paginated page or less than 30 if there aren't enough records)

If the user's on page 2, then get 31-60 and so on.  How would I go about setting the logic for that in my controller?  I've tried too many things to mention, I just need another pair of eyes.

Here's controller code:

```
try {

        $inventoryList =  $this->_inventoryRepository->getInventories();

        if($inventoryList['current_page'] <= 0) {
            $inventoryList['current_page'] = 1;
        }

        $inventoryList['per_page'] = 30; // 30 entries per page
        $inventoryList['current_page'] = (int) get_value($inventoryList["current_page"], 1); // the current page, default will be 1
        $totalRecords = $inventoryList['total']; // total number of records 88

        // now I have all records
        // if page is 2 and total records for page is 30, then acquire records from 31-60
        
        return [
            'isValid' => true,
            'list' => $inventoryList,
            'page' => $inventoryList['current_page'],
            'totalRecords' => $totalRecords,
            'pageSize' => $inventoryList['per_page'],
            'message' => 'Successfully fetched inventories list'
        ];
    } catch( Exception $exception) {
        return [
            'isValid' => false,
            'code' => $exception->getCode(),
            'systemMessage' => $exception->getMessage(),
            'message' => "Something went wrong"
        ];
    }
```

Here's the paginated query:

```
$this->model
  ->distinct()
  ->with('table.rewards')
  ->select($attributes['inventory'])
  ->paginate();
```